# If I cancel Login Dialog, login error occurs: Unauthorized Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

While try to execute code below Login dialog box display and if I cancel login error occur Unauthorized Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //verify that resquest is for api
        if (Request.Path.ToLower().StartsWith("/api/v1"))
        {
            if (Response.StatusCode == 302)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 401;
                Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Write("\"fail\"");
            }
            else if (Response.StatusCode == 500)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Write("\"server error\"");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what `401` means.

Comment: then what do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP code 401 means "unauthorized". When the browser receives this error code, it assumes it's because the user needs to login. The browser displays a login dialog, and then tries again with the login details given.

**This is exactly what's supposed to happen.**

If what you're wanting is to simply refuse the request, you're after HTTP code 403, "forbidden".

However, I'm not clear on why you're actually trying to achieve here. If your own server code is returning an HTTP 302 (a redirect), why are you trying to convert that to an HTTP 401/403/whatever? If you don't want to perform redirects for some reason, don't issue the redirect in the first place!

Comment: I have Ipay.com.np website in asp.net MVC where I have implement some API for mobile apps and when I set Status code as we need in some of case it redirect as per IIS like when i set status code 401 it redirect to Invalid Session. I don't want to happend this in that case .


Is there any to avoid IIS redirect page in certail URL..